# Как узнать адрес структуры, зная адрес одной из переменных внутри? С++, WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, память

Предположим есть структура вроде такой:

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}
```

Предположим, что у меня есть адрес переменной одного из экземпляров `Foo`. Как я могу получить адрес начала этой структуры в памяти процесса? Потыкал WinAPI, но ничего не смог придумать

Comment: Просто вычесть из адреса поля смещение этого поля относительно начала структуры.

Comment: Если под перменной вы имеете в виду адрес одного из полей структуры, например `Foo x; &x.c`, то  -- `#define container_of(field_addr,type,field_name)  ((type *)((char *)(field_addr) - (char *)&((type *)0)->field_name))`

Comment: @user7860670 а можно немного подробнее? Перерыл кучу интернета и литературы, но не нашел ничего, что мне помогло бы. Про смещения я и так знаю, но как их найти - вот в чем вопрос. Слышал, что делается раскрутка стека вызовов, но я так и не понял зачем

Comment: @avp спасибо за код, но не понятно что этот макрос делает, можно подробнее, пожалуйста?

Comment: upd: сейчас нашел информацию про сишный макрос offsetof, но возвращает он size_t. Насколько это правильный подход?

Comment: @ComeInRage,   `Foo *get_struct_Foo_addr_having_c_field_addr (int *c_addr) {Foo *struct_addr = container_of(c_addr, Foo, c); return struct_addr;}` Это пример, как им пользоваться. Макрос получает адрес поля, тип структуры и *имя поля*. Он вычисляет смещение этого поля `(char *)&((type *)0)->field_name)` (по сути, это содержимое макроса `offset_of`) от начала структуры и вычитает его из адреса поля. Получается адрес начала структуры, содержащей это поле. (Такие макросы часто используются при программиовании списков и деревьев на Си)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Макрос **offsetof** даёт смещение элемента структуры. Сначала нужно адрес элемента преобразовать на тип, имеющий размер 1 байт. Делаем сначала `(char*)`. Потом отнимаем смещение в байтах и преобразовываем на тип структуры.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Foo {
    int i;
    char c;
    float f;
};

int  main()       {
  struct Foo foo ;
  int * const pi = & foo .  i ;
  char * const pc = & foo . c ;
  float * const pf = & foo . f ;
  struct Foo * const fi = (struct Foo *)((char*)pi-offsetof(struct Foo,i));
  struct Foo * const fc = (struct Foo *)((char*)pc-offsetof(struct Foo,c));
  struct Foo * const ff = (struct Foo *)((char*)pf-offsetof(struct Foo,f));
  printf("& foo = %p\n",&foo);
  printf("pi = %p\n",pi);
  printf("pc = %p\n",pc);
  printf("pf = %p\n",pf);
  printf("fi = %p\n",fi);
  printf("fc = %p\n",fc);
  printf("ff = %p\n",ff);
}
```

проверка :

```
& foo = 0x7ffdf08aef74
pi = 0x7ffdf08aef74
pc = 0x7ffdf08aef78
pf = 0x7ffdf08aef7c
fi = 0x7ffdf08aef74
fc = 0x7ffdf08aef74
ff = 0x7ffdf08aef74
```

адреса `pi`,`pc`,`pf` - указывают на эти элементы, и потом из них вычисляется адрес структуры.

Comment: `offsetof` это не функция, а макрос.

Comment: Согласен, так как имя переменной к сожалению не передаётся по значению, как в Лиспе. исправил. @αλεχολυτ